# c# - get square root and nearest prime

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a program to get an input's square root and the input's nearest prime. I can't figure out what could be the problem when getting the nearest prime but it doesn't return the correct answer.

```
using System;

namespace SqrtPrime
{
class SqrtPrime
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int num, ctr;
        Console.Write("Enter number: ");
        num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] inp = new int[num];

        for (ctr = 0; ctr < num; ctr++)
        {
            Console.Write("\n\nEnter number {0}: ", ctr + 1);
            inp[ctr] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            double sqrt = Math.Sqrt(inp[ctr]);
            Console.Write("\nSquare root: {0} ", sqrt);
            int cnvt = inp[ctr];

            Console.Write("\nNearest prime number/s: ");
            int i, Prime1 = 0, Prime2 = 0;
            bool checkPrime1 = true, checkPrime2 = true;

            while (checkPrime1)
            {
                cnvt--;
                for (i = 2; i <= cnvt; i++)
                {
                    if (cnvt % i == 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (i == cnvt)
                {
                    checkPrime1 = false;
                    Prime1 = cnvt;
                    break;
                }
            }

            while (checkPrime2)
            {
                cnvt++;
                for (i = 2; i <= cnvt; i++)
                {
                    if (cnvt % i == 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (i == cnvt)
                {
                    Prime2 = cnvt;
                    checkPrime2 = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (Prime2 - cnvt > cnvt - Prime1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Prime1);
            }

            else if (Prime2 - cnvt < cnvt - Prime1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Prime2);
            }

            else if (Prime2 - cnvt == cnvt - Prime1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Prime1 + ", " + Prime2);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Side note: I suggest *extracting a method*, `public static bool IsPrime(int value)`

Comment: can I have any example for that one please? :)

Answer (score 5):

I suggest *extracting methods*, first `IsPrime`

```
public static bool IsPrime(int value) {
  if (value <= 1)
    return false;
  else if (value % 2 == 0)
    return value == 2;

  int n = (int) (Math.Sqrt(value) + 0.5);

  for (int i = 3; i <= n; i += 2)
    if (value % i == 0)
      return false;

  return true;
}
```

Then `primeBelow` and `primeAbove`

```
private static int primeBelow(double value) {
  int n = (int) value;

  for (int i = n; i >= 2; --i)
    if (IsPrime(i))
      return i;

  return -1; // technical value, e.g. there's no prime below for sqrt(3)  
}

private static int primeAbove(double value) {
  int n = (int) value;

  for (int i = n; ; ++i)
    if (IsPrime(i) && (i > value))
      return i;

  return -1;   
}
```

finally, `NearestPrime`

```
private static string NearestPrime(double value) {
  int below = primeBelow(value);
  int above = primeAbove(value);

  if (below < 0)
    return above.ToString();

  if (Math.Abs(value - below) < Math.Abs(value - above)) 
    return below.ToString();
  else if (Math.Abs(value - below) > Math.Abs(value - above)) 
    return above.ToString();
  else 
    return string.Format("{0}, {1}", below, above);
}
```

Then use them

```
   ...
   double sqrt = Math.Sqrt(inp[ctr]);
   Console.Write("\nSquare root: {0} ", sqrt); 
   Console.WriteLine(NearestPrime(sqrt));
```

Comment: One note, IsPrime is a fairly inefficient implementation, you may want to look in to things like the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) to get much faster ways for building a list of prime numbers. Also, build the list once and cache it.

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain: you're quite right, the implementation is not the fastest, but IMHO, the simplest one (while being good enough). Using a precomputed `HashSet<int>` of primes is a good idea, but my goal was to show the method: step by step implementation instead of cramming all the code into one single `Main`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested you should put some of your logic in helper methods, here is a simple solution on getting the square root of a number and the next and last prime number.

```
class SqrtPrime
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter number: ");
            int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Square Root is: " + Math.Sqrt(number) + "\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Next Prime is " + CheckPrimeUpwards(number) + "\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Last Prime was " + CheckPrimeDownwards(number) + "\n");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static int CheckPrimeDownwards(int number)
        {
            int result = number;

            while(!IsNumberAPrime(result))
            {
                result--;
            }

            return result;
        }

        static int CheckPrimeUpwards(int number)
        {
            int result = number;

            while (!IsNumberAPrime(result))
            {
                result++;
            }

            return result;
        }

        public static bool IsNumberAPrime(int number)
        {
            int boundary = (int)Math.Floor(Math.Sqrt(number));

            if (number < 2)
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (number == 2)
            {
                return true;
            }

            for (int i = 2; i <= boundary; ++i)
            {
                if (number % i == 0)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Counter examples for `IsNumberAPrime`: `-1`, `0`